# Horizontal tree view control in .net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, controls

I'm looking for a horizontal tree view control that creates nodes in the following way -

```
                                    |_______|
                                        |
                             _______________________
                            |                       |
                        |_______|               |_______|
                            |
                  _______________________
                 |                       |
             |_______|               |_______|
```

Hope you get the design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google around for an "Organization Chart" control.  That will most likely have the tree structure you want.

Comment: Okie, that was the exact key words i was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, there are a bunch of them out there.  I haven't tried any myself, so I can't give you a good recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out : [Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) or some commercial ones such as [this.](http://edraw-organizational-chart.edrawsoft.qarchive.org/) (first hit)