# Horizontal Tree(view) in Winforms or WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, treeview

I have an old **Winforms application** with a **normel treeview** for representing more or less complex hierarchical structures. For some reasons the users of the application now also want to get a **horizontal representation** of the treeview (like [this web control](http://www.orgchartasp.net/)).

So what is the best way and effective way to transform a normal (Winforms) treeview into such a representation? Are there **controls (Winforms or WPF)**, which provide an easy way to "draw" such horizontal trees?

Comment: Why don't you ask google first? or use search? [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608520/horizontal-tree-view-control-in-net), [click](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17025/Custom-TreeView-Layout-in-WPF)..

Answer (score 2):

Here is josh smith`s post similar to your requirement

[Organization Chart](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17025/Custom-TreeView-Layout-in-WPF)

Hope this helps!!